# Template function in eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0 for Windows CE

Tags: c++, visual-c++, embedded, windows-ce, template-function

Does eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0 (SP4) support template functions? I get an error when I try to compile code that works fine in Visual C++ 6.0.

### Here is my template function, which does compile:

```
template<class NodeType>
NodeType* MyFunction()
{
    // ... do stuff
    return new NodeType("foo"); // return a new class instance of type NodeType
}
```

### Template Function Usage:

```
MyClass *myOjb = MyFunction<MyClass>(); // this is causing an error
```

### Compilation Errors:

```
error C2275: 'MyClass' : illegal use of this type as an expression
                         see declaration of 'MyClass'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Is there some compiler switch I need to change? How do I get this to compile?

Comment: Ouch, stuck with VC4, good luck!

Comment: Yeah, it's for a legacy application.

Comment: +1 I don't usually upvote self-answered questions, but this one is definitely a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-90884.html).

"It works fine when the template function is not a class member. Oh well, I guess I'll have
to leave it as a global function."